# How to select the last item in a LoadMoreListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview

I implement a custom load more Expandable list view, where I add a pull to load more feature at the bottom to the original expandable list view.

However, I could not select a button in the last item of the list view, because every time I pull down, it always execute the onLoadMore function, do we have any idea to overcome this issues of the loadmore Listview ?

**1) Fragment xml layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/CourierPullToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <joyporter.danielwirelesssoftware.com.adapter.user_job_manage.listview.LoadMoreExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/courier_manage_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </joyporter.danielwirelesssoftware.com.adapter.user_job_manage.listview.LoadMoreExpandableListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I try to add a additional empty view after the listview, but it does not work

**2) tried xml layout but does not work:**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/CourierPullToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <joyporter.danielwirelesssoftware.com.adapter.user_job_manage.listview.LoadMoreExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/courier_manage_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </joyporter.danielwirelesssoftware.com.adapter.user_job_manage.listview.LoadMoreExpandableListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
```

**3) Screenshot of the list view**
[image]

**4) Screenshot when I try to click the button, but it execute the onLoadMoreFunction:** 
[image]

All ideas are welcome. Thank you very much

Comment: You can find how to build a load more button in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467638/how-to-add-fixed-button-in-recyclerview-adapter/32468965#32468965

Comment: Hi Xiaomi, thank you for your comment, you have any other suggestions, since the app requirement does not want to have a load more button ?